# GUI editor for Java GWT ui binder

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, gwt

I am new to programming,

Can anyone suggest how to construct/edit the user interface in Java GWT with ui binder. A GUI editor/designer should be handy but unfortunately I couldn't find one

I am working on an existing project that uses Java and GWT with ui binder with the ui.xml files.
Eclipse Luna as the ide(python in the backend that's another story)

Searched across the internet to find that there is a GWT designer tool but that is discontinued on latest GWT. Rest all other tutorials says to add/edit the .java and .ui.xml codes which is a tired process as my project has got plenty of sheets.

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: there's one from vaadin, not free i think

Comment: Many thanks I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it by hand.

No editor exists anymore. The old editor you found is dead. 
I guess because it was not good enough. 
Never used it, programming should be done by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a work around(as I wouldn't consider this an actual fix/answer)

Here is what I did
Loaded my Project onto Eclipse Kepler with GWT 2.6.1(this version has the fixed designer tool)
Voila, it works like a charm and now I can easily edit/modify the UI.
I know its a dead end if I can't move with an updated version, but its okay for now.
Hope I find an alternate.

Many thanks for the suggestions and answers.

Comment: P.S., the GWT designer tool is discontinued by the dev team and is now replace by the WindowsBuilder(which works more with Swing and SWT).

Comment: I would like to know where did you find that info regarding WindowBuilder @Gul?